# How to get nested ArrayList from JSON

Tags: android, kotlin

I have three nested array in my main array.
It is my model:

```
data class Test (val id: Int,
                 val numberQuestion: String,
                 val question: String,
                 val questionImageSrc: String,
                 val examination: Boolean,
                 val typeQuestion: String,
                 val singleChoiceAnswers: ArrayList<singleChoiseAnswer>,
                 val multipleChoiceAnswers: ArrayList<multipleChoiceAnswers>,
                 val inputAnswer: ArrayList<inputAnswer>)

data class multipleChoiceAnswers(val letter: String,
                                 val text: String,
                                 val correctAnswer: Boolean,
                                 val checked: Boolean)

data class singleChoiseAnswer(val letter: String,
                              val text: String,
                              val correctAnswer: Boolean,
                              val checked: Boolean)

data class inputAnswer(val correctAnswer: String,
                        val userAnswer: String)
```

And I must take data from json, but i dont know hot to put data to the nested array.
It is my code:

```
private fun jsonResult(jsonString: String?) {

            val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonString)

            val list = ArrayList<Test>()
            val slist = ArrayList<singleChoiseAnswer>()
            val mlist = ArrayList<multipleChoiceAnswers>()
            var i = 0
            var j = 0

            while (i < jsonArray.length()) {
                val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                list.add(
                    Test(
                        jsonObject.getInt("id"),
                        jsonObject.getString("numberQuestion"),
                        jsonObject.getString("question"),
                        jsonObject.getString("questionImageSrc"),
                        jsonObject.getBoolean("examination"),
                        jsonObject.getString("typeQuestion"),
                        singleChoiseAnswer(
                            jsonObject.optString("letter"),
                            jsonObject.optString("text"),
                            jsonObject.optBoolean("correctAnswer"),
                            jsonObject.optBoolean("checked"),
                        multipleChoiceAnswers(
                            jsonObject.optString("letter"),
                            jsonObject.optString("text"),
                            jsonObject.optBoolean("correctAnswer"),
                            jsonObject.optBoolean("checked")
                        ),
                        inputAnswer(
                            jsonObject.optString("correctAnswer"),
                            jsonObject.optString("userAnswer")
                        )
                    )
                )
                i++
            }
```

My JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 1",
        "question": "Прочитайте текст и выполните задания 1—3.\n\n(1)Тропический лес — лес, распространённый в тропическом, экваториальном и субэкваториальном поясах. (2)В этих широтах встречающиеся воздушные течения приносят в регион в любое время года большое количество осадков, сочетающихся с жарким климатом. (3)… для тропической местности характерна роскошная буйная растительность.\n\n➤Укажите два предложения, в которых верно передана ГЛАВНАЯ информация, содержащаяся в тексте.",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "multipleChoice",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [
            {
                "letter": "А.",
                "text": "В тропических, экваториальных и субэкваториальных широтах встречающиеся воздушные течения приносят в регион в любое время года большое количество осадков, которые сочетаются с жарким климатом.",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Б.",
                "text": "Тропический лес — лес, распространённый в тропическом, экваториальном и субэкваториальном поясах, для которых характерно большое количество осадков и жаркий климат, что создает условия для роста роскошной буйной растительности.",
                "correctAnswer": true,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "В.",
                "text": "Тропический лес — лес, распространённый в тропическом, экваториальном и субэкваториальном поясах, для которого характерна буйная растительность.",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Г.",
                "text": "Тропический лес произрастает в тропических, экваториальных и субэкваториальных широтах, где большое количество осадков в сочетании с жарким климатом создает условия для роста роскошной буйной растительности.",
                "correctAnswer": true,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Д.",
                "text": "Для тропической местности характерна роскошная буйная растительность.",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            }
        ],
        "inputAnswer": []
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 2",
        "question": "Прочитайте текст и выполните задания 1—3.\n\n(1)Тропический лес — лес, распространённый в тропическом, экваториальном и субэкваториальном поясах. (2)В этих широтах встречающиеся воздушные течения приносят в регион в любое время года большое количество осадков, сочетающихся с жарким климатом. (3)… для тропической местности характерна роскошная буйная растительность.\n\n➤Какое из приведённых ниже слов (сочетаний слов) должно быть на месте пропуска в третьем (3) предложении?",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "singleChoice",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [
            {
                "letter": "А.",
                "text": "Даже",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Б.",
                "text": "Поэтому",
                "correctAnswer": true,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "В.",
                "text": "Однако",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Г.",
                "text": "Хотя",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Д.",
                "text": "Напротив,",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            }
        ],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 3",
        "question": "Прочитайте текст и выполните задания 1—3.\n\n(1)Тропический лес — лес, распространённый в тропическом, экваториальном и субэкваториальном поясах. (2)В этих широтах встречающиеся воздушные течения приносят в регион в любое время года большое количество осадков, сочетающихся с жарким климатом. (3)… для тропической местности характерна роскошная буйная растительность.\n\n➤Прочитайте фрагмент словарной статьи, в которой приводятся значения слова ПОЯС. Определите значение, в котором это слово употреблено в первом (1) предложении текста. Укажите цифру, соответствующую этому значению в приведённом фрагменте словарной статьи. \n\nПОЯС, -а, -ов.",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "singleChoice",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [
            {
                "letter": "А.",
                "text": "Лента, шнур, ремень или прошитая полоса ткани для завязывания, застегивания по талии. Кожаный п",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Б.",
                "text": "перен. Пространство, окружающее, опоясывающее что-н. Лесопарковый (зеленый) п. столицы",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "В.",
                "text": "Пространство, выделяемое внутри территории страны на основании каких-н. собственных признаков. Тарифный п",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Г.",
                "text": "Выделяемая по какому-н. признаку часть земной поверхности (между какими-н. параллелями или между двумя меридианами), а также часть небесной сферы. Физико-географический п. Часовой п. П. зодиака",
                "correctAnswer": true,
                "checked": false
            }
        ],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 4",
        "question": "В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Укажите это слово.",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "singleChoice",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [
            {
                "letter": "А.",
                "text": "зАгодя",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Б.",
                "text": "бАлованный",
                "correctAnswer": true,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "В.",
                "text": "исчЕрпать",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Г.",
                "text": "щЁлкать",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Д.",
                "text": "новостЕй",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            }
        ],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 5",
        "question": "В одном из приведённых ниже предложений НЕВЕРНО употреблено выделенное слово. Исправьте лексическую ошибку, подобрав к выделенному слову пароним. Запишите подобранное слово.\n\nЗАЧИНЩИК русского национального театра А. Н. Островский сумел передать в своих пьесах дух замоскворечной Москвы. \n\nНа уроке русского языка шестиклассники писали ДИКТАНТ. \n\nНе стоит падать духом, столкнувшись с рядовыми ЖИТЕЙСКИМИ трудностями. \n\nНа кинофестивале фильм русского режиссера получил приз ЗРИТЕЛЬСКИХ симпатий. \n\nМногие АБОНЕНТЫ телефонной сети были недовольны из-за возникших неполадок на линии.",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "input",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": [
            {
                "correctAnswer": "зачинатель",
                "userAnswer": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 6",
        "question": "В одном из выделенных ниже слов допущена ошибка в образовании формы слова. Исправьте ошибку и запишите слово правильно. \n\nболее ПЯТИСТА рублей \nпара ЧУЛОК \nнужные АДРЕСА \nподписать ДОГОВОРЫ \nкилограмм ТОМАТОВ",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "input",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": [
            {
                "correctAnswer": "пятисот",
                "userAnswer": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 7",
        "question": "Определите слово, в котором пропущена безударная чередующаяся гласная корня. Выпишите это слово, вставив пропущенную букву. \n\nоч..рованный \nпом..стье \nст..пендия \nприк..снуться \nп..риферия",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "input",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": [
            {
                "correctAnswer": "прикоснуться",
                "userAnswer": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 8",
        "question": "Определите ряд, в котором в обоих словах пропущена одна и та же буква. Выпишите эти слова, вставив пропущенную букву. Ответ запишите без пробелов, разделяя слова ТОЛЬКО ЗАПЯТОЙ БЕЗ ПРОБЕЛА. \n\nра..смотреть, бе..цветный \nпр..брежный, пр..милый \nпр..дедушка, под..брать \nпред..юльский, вз..мать \nраз..скать, контр..гра",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "input",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": [
            {
                "correctAnswer": "рассмотреть,бесцветный",
                "userAnswer": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "numberQuestion": "Вопрос 9",
        "question": "Укажите слово, в котором на месте пропуска пишется буква E.",
        "questionImageSrc": "",
        "examination": false,
        "typeQuestion": "singleChoice",
        "singleChoiceAnswers": [
            {
                "letter": "А.",
                "text": "завис..мый",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Б.",
                "text": "просматр..вать",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "В.",
                "text": "алюмини..вый",
                "correctAnswer": true,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Г.",
                "text": "красав..ца",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "letter": "Д.",
                "text": "прикле..в",
                "correctAnswer": false,
                "checked": false
            }
        ],
        "multipleChoiceAnswers": [],
        "inputAnswer": []
    }
```

Comment: please add yout json file here.

Comment: @hasan, you can see it below

Comment: please remove your json file from Answer(below) and add it here(top section).

Comment: @hasanhasan, or i can give a link to json [JSON](http://sasmobile.ru/resources/ege/dataJSON/russianLanguage/tests/russianLanguageTest.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- check for `"typeQuestion": "multipleChoice"`
see if it contain single or muliple or input type.
2- if it contaon `"multipleChoice"`  then 
   get `"multipleChoice"` convert `"multipleChoice"` to JOSNObject extract each value.
3- check for other `"typeQuestion"` condition parse them
4- at last add them to your list.

here is code

```
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

            val typeQuestion = jsonObject.getString("typeQuestion"); // other keys here
            Timber.d("typeQuestion $typeQuestion")// typeQuestion multipleChoice
            //for multipleChoice
            if(typeQuestion.contains("multipleChoice")){

                val multipleChoiceAnswers = jsonObject.getJSONArray("multipleChoiceAnswers")
                // run a for loop for this for this
                for (sc in 0 until multipleChoiceAnswers.length()){
                    val currentMCA = multipleChoiceAnswers.getJSONObject(sc)
                    val letter = currentMCA.getString("letter")
                    //... extract other value for multipleChoiceAnswers
                    // mlist.add(multipleChoiceAnswers) 

                   // val letter = currentMCA.getInt("id")
                    Timber.d("multipleChoiceAnswers  size ${multipleChoiceAnswers.length()}  id $letter    ")



                }
            }

            // for singleChoice
            if(typeQuestion.contains("singleChoice")){
                val singleChoiceAnswers = jsonObject.getJSONArray("singleChoiceAnswers")
                // run a for loop for this for this
                for (sc in 0 until singleChoiceAnswers.length()){
                     // exract singleChoiceAnswers value as multipleChoice

                }
            }
            // for input
            if(typeQuestion.contains("input")){

            }

             // Add all data to main list i.e test 
            //list.add();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make java classes for your json.
these are the classes of your relevent json string.

---

First java class is Test.java

```
    import java.util.List;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
    public class Test {
    @SerializedName(“id”)
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName(“numberQuestion”)
    @Expose
    private String numberQuestion;
    @SerializedName(“question”)
    @Expose
    private String question;
    @SerializedName(“questionImageSrc”)
    @Expose
    private String questionImageSrc;
    @SerializedName(“examination”)
    @Expose
    private Boolean examination;
    @SerializedName(“typeQuestion”)
    @Expose
    private String typeQuestion;
    @SerializedName(“singleChoiceAnswers”)
    @Expose
    private List<SingleChoiceAnswer> singleChoiceAnswers = null;
    @SerializedName(“multipleChoiceAnswers”)
    @Expose
    private List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> multipleChoiceAnswers = null;
    @SerializedName(“inputAnswer”)
    @Expose
    private List<InputAnswer> inputAnswer = null;
    public Integer getId() {
    return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNumberQuestion() {
    return numberQuestion;
    }
    public void setNumberQuestion(String numberQuestion) {
    this.numberQuestion = numberQuestion;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
    }
    public String getQuestionImageSrc() {
    return questionImageSrc;
    }
    public void setQuestionImageSrc(String questionImageSrc) {
    this.questionImageSrc = questionImageSrc;
    }
    public Boolean getExamination() {
    return examination;
    }
    public void setExamination(Boolean examination) {
    this.examination = examination;
    }
    public String getTypeQuestion() {
    return typeQuestion;
    }
    public void setTypeQuestion(String typeQuestion) {
    this.typeQuestion = typeQuestion;
    }
    public List<SingleChoiceAnswer> getSingleChoiceAnswers() {
    return singleChoiceAnswers;
    }
    public void setSingleChoiceAnswers(List<SingleChoiceAnswer> singleChoiceAnswers) {
    this.singleChoiceAnswers = singleChoiceAnswers;
    }
    public List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> getMultipleChoiceAnswers() {
    return multipleChoiceAnswers;
    }
    public void setMultipleChoiceAnswers(List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> multipleChoiceAnswers) {
    this.multipleChoiceAnswers = multipleChoiceAnswers;
    }
    public List<InputAnswer> getInputAnswer() {
    return inputAnswer;
    }
    public void setInputAnswer(List<InputAnswer> inputAnswer) {
    this.inputAnswer = inputAnswer;
    }
    }
```

---

Second java class is InputAnswer.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class InputAnswer {
@SerializedName(“correctAnswer”)
@Expose
private String correctAnswer;
@SerializedName(“userAnswer”)
@Expose
private String userAnswer;
public String getCorrectAnswer() {
return correctAnswer;
}
public void setCorrectAnswer(String correctAnswer) {
this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
public String getUserAnswer() {
return userAnswer;
}
public void setUserAnswer(String userAnswer) {
this.userAnswer = userAnswer;
}
}
```

---

Third java class is MultipleChoiceAnswer.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class MultipleChoiceAnswer {
@SerializedName(“letter”)
@Expose
private String letter;
@SerializedName(“text”)
@Expose
private String text;
@SerializedName(“correctAnswer”)
@Expose
private Boolean correctAnswer;
@SerializedName(“checked”)
@Expose
private Boolean checked;
public String getLetter() {
return letter;
}
public void setLetter(String letter) {
this.letter = letter;
}
public String getText() {
return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
this.text = text;
}
public Boolean getCorrectAnswer() {
return correctAnswer;
}
public void setCorrectAnswer(Boolean correctAnswer) {
this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
public Boolean getChecked() {
return checked;
}
public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
this.checked = checked;
}
}
```

---

Forth java class is SingleChoiceAnswer.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class SingleChoiceAnswer {
@SerializedName(“letter”)
@Expose
private String letter;
@SerializedName(“text”)
@Expose
private String text;
@SerializedName(“correctAnswer”)
@Expose
private Boolean correctAnswer;
@SerializedName(“checked”)
@Expose
private Boolean checked;
public String getLetter() {
return letter;
}
public void setLetter(String letter) {
this.letter = letter;
}
public String getText() {
return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
this.text = text;
}
public Boolean getCorrectAnswer() {
return correctAnswer;
}
public void setCorrectAnswer(Boolean correctAnswer) {
this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
public Boolean getChecked() {
return checked;
}
public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
this.checked = checked;
}
}
```

---

Add [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)  :

```
dependencies {
  implementation ‘com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6’
}
```

---

Now you just have to call these lines :

```
Test testdata=new Gson().fromJson(JsonString,Test.class);
testdata.getMultipleChoiceAnswers()
```

---